# HDFS is not working?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to set up multi nodes hadoop on three virtual machines running Ubuntu operating system.

I set up everything right: I ssh from any of them to another. I configure hadoop files.

```
enter code here
*This is core.site-xml*

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://Master1:54310</value>
</property>
</configuration>

This is hdfs-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/hadoop/name/</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>/hadoop/data</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>2</value>
</property>
</configuration>

This is mapred.site-xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>Master1:54311</value> // this is my hostname for master node
</property>
</configuration>

![enter image description here][1]
```

command line:

```
 inside hadoop I typed on command line:
 bin/hadoop namenode -format
 bin/hadoop start-all.sh
 jps
 bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report
enter code here
```

the outputs in the pictures below:
Thank you in advance and I am looking forward your help

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the below property in hdfs-site.xml then try

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:/home/user/hadoop/name/</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:/home/user/hadoop/data</value>
</property>
```

I checked the log, it should be path error. Change it to appropriate path as above or create two folders /home/user/hadoop/name and /home/user/hadoop/data and set its path in the hdfs-site.xml file.

**Log**

```
2015-06-24 02:57:19,997 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Invalid directory in dfs.data.dir: can not create directory: /hadoop/data
2015-06-24 02:57:19,997 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: All directories in dfs.data.dir are invalid.
2015-06-24 02:57:19,998 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Comment: Hi Kumar. I add your comment but nothing change. I still did not get the name node and data node.

Comment: Hi Kumar: This is the output in the link below. It does not work. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eos66b7d150hl9j/AAC7QJaEt9xGqgCQhiXWvgSYa?dl=0

Comment: Ok: I found this folder in /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.2/logs. I upload all files in this folder. Check the link.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6q94w85rzlxgm1/logs.zip?dl=0

Comment: Make sure you have changed the value as **file:/home/yourusername/hadoop/name/** for name directory and **file:/home/yourusername/hadoop/data/** for data directory. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,according to the second pic, you maybe don't close the hadoop process before you run the new hadoop process.So try this commond `ps -e|grep java` and kill all java process.

Then, you must confirm that you have the permission to write the directories "/hadoop/*"(look at the third pic), this is a basic option.

At last, run again.

Comment: Hi gwgyk: Thank you for your reply. I solved the permission problem which in the third picture by adding (sudo). However, i still did not have namenode and datanode when I type jps.

Comment: Please do again as I side and post your error information

Comment: Hi gwgyk: I cannot upload the pictures but I upload them on dropbox. if you click the link, you will find the pictures https://www.dropbox.com/sh/29imphzhaxtl36p/AAD29eiCzSORKYJcTB4y4Tega?dl=0

Comment: I am sorry I can't access the website because of some reason.Please post the log information, the log files on the ${HADOOP_HOME}.

Comment: Hi gygyk: this is the link for logs file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6q94w85rzlxgm1/logs.zip?dl=0                         Also: I do not know where is the HADOOP_HOME.

Comment: Does the node of your cluster can connection? Do you config the ssh?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. The problem was that I have not created directories for hdfs and when I created the folders, with some change in configuration it works. Next week or so, I will post all steps for configurations and run hadoop on full distributed mode.

Sincerely
Salem

Answer (score 0):

Stop some servers if you have multiple servers running 
▪ sudo service mysqld stop /* this stops mysql server */ 
▪ sudo service mongod stop 
stop mysqld when you are running Hadoop hdfs, due to lack of main memory
Run:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /
```